# How to check if url-redirection occured

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, redirect, onload

My tool can display external websites in an iFrame.
Few sites (e.g. "http://ec.asm.org/") are loading in my iFrame but after few seconds reloads on the same browser's tab but not as iFrame.

I suspects that it happens because the destination websites changing their `location` (redirection) to the same url during the page load (onLoad).

Is there way to verify this assumption (redirection to the same page)?
Is there any other possible reason for this problem (iFrame closed)?

Comment: Nothing you can do. It is a common frame busting technique. They check if window their page is in is `top` window. If not they redirect the top window. Your code is gone at that point

Comment: I don't want to do nothing in such case - I just want to VERIFY that this is the case to ensure that there is no other problem with my iFrame...

Comment: You are fine.There are numerous frame busting approaches and you can not detect them in advance. It simply boils down to not all sites can be put in iframe